# creating multiple checkboxes in angular 9 not working for me

Tags: javascript, angular, checkbox, angular9, formgroups

I have the need for a table containing a checkbox for every row in the table.
I'm using Angular 9.

The table is defined in a form and I use an ngFor to create each row in the table.
In the ngFor I loop over a collection of messages and I create a row for each message.

The user should be able to check the checkbox and the push a button to resend the selected messages.

The way I've written my code I do get errors I can't explain.

I have created a stackblitz thingy to share my code.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4qqrzf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
There are some things wrong with this code in Stackblitz.
The most annoying one is that it keeps saying that it's loading while nothing seems to happen.
I must be missing something there.

If I run the code on my own system I get this error:

```
[Error] ERROR – TypeError: this.form.controls.orders.push is not a function. (In 'this.form.controls.orders.push(control)', 'this.form.controls.orders.push' is undefined) — app.component.ts:36
TypeError: this.form.controls.orders.push is not a function. (In 'this.form.controls.orders.push(control)', 'this.form.controls.orders.push' is undefined) — app.component.ts:36
    defaultErrorLogger (vendor.js:12499)
    handleError (vendor.js:12552)
    run (polyfills.js:136)
    (anonymous function) (vendor.js:45404)
    onInvoke (vendor.js:44403)
    run (polyfills.js:136)
    (anonymous function) (polyfills.js:870)
    onInvokeTask (vendor.js:44381)
    runTask (polyfills.js:180)
    drainMicroTaskQueue (polyfills.js:582)
    promiseReactionJob
```

I have copied most of the code from https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stszta?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts where this problem does not occur.

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {FormArray, FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  form: FormGroup;
  ordersData = [
    { id: 100, name: 'order 1' },
    { id: 200, name: 'order 2' },
    { id: 300, name: 'order 3' },
    { id: 400, name: 'order 4' }
  ];

  berichten = [
    {messageId: 123},
    {messageId: 234},
    {messageId: 345},
    {messageId: 456},
    {messageId: 567}
  ];

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      orders: []
    });
    this.addCheckboxes();
  }

  private addCheckboxes() {
    this.ordersData.forEach((o, i) => {
      const control = new FormControl(i === 0); // if first item set to true, else false
      (this.form.controls.orders as FormArray).push(control);
    });
  }

  submit() {
    const selectedOrderIds = this.form.value.orders
      .map((v, i) => (v ? this.ordersData[i].id : null))
      .filter(v => v !== null);
    console.log(selectedOrderIds);
  }
}
```

app.component.html:

```
  <table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <b>Selection</b>
      </td>
      <td>
        <b>MessageId</b>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let bericht of berichten; let i = index" >
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" [formControlName]="i">
      </td>
      <td>
        {{bericht.messageId}}
      </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>
```

What am I doing wrong? (In Stackblitz and in my code)

Comment: Can you include the relevant code in the question?

Comment: stackblitz is not working, change <app-root>loading</app-root>

Comment: code added. Fixed stackBlitz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Form is shown with these changes:

```
//constructor     
orders: new FormArray([])



`//addCheckboxes`
(this.form.get('orders') as FormArray).push(control);
```

In template remove the binding to a control which does not exist

```
[formControlName]="i"
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. Would you mind to explain, if possible, why:(this.form.get('orders') as FormArray).push(control); works and my: (this.form.controls.orders as FormArray).push(control); doesn't? My example was copied from a working solution on StackBlitz .

Comment: this.form.controls is an array of FormControls and does not have a property orders. this.form.get('orders') asks in the form for a control (can be a group/control/formarray) with the name 'orders'